# How to query a user for an array for a specific document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to query a user through a cookie like so

```
User.findById(req.signedCookies.userid,
```

and then query an array within the user for another user id.

The array is friendRequest and I am querying for another user's id. I then want to return true or false depending whether or not the user's id exists.

This is for mongoDB.  (I am using mongoose with node.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query to check if a user exists would be

User.find({_id: req.signedCookies.userid, friendRequest: friendRequesId})

this will only return a result if the user match and it contains a matching friendRequest

example

```
> db.t.insert({id: 1, users:[2,3,4]})
> db.t.findOne({id:1, users: 2})
```